# Help Mulberry ID

Tags: mulberry

[image: My small mulberry]

I got it from a nursery in CA by order online last June. Now this website is gone. I doubt this tree is not Pakistan Mulberry.

Comment: The ID of some trees, especially between varieties of a particular tree type, is a challenge before they have full-sized leaves. This one appears to still be small enough to have immature leaves. You might have to let these grow a year or two to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

Mulberry plants all around where I am have leaves that change season to season. this could be, but the proper identification probably isnt possible because of that fact. Could just wait and find out

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32908)